# D3 : how to use hideAxis in parcoords with dropdown menu

Tags: d3.js, selection, parallel-coordinates

I am following the example from the [here](https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/) and trying to implement the hiding of axis on selection like it is done in the case of bundling in the example.

But I am able to show the drop-down menu but my hiding option is not working but its getting updated only.

here is my code :
**.html**

```
     <div id="bundleDimension">Bundle using clusters determined by: </div>
    </p>

    <div id="hideAxis">Hide the axis of selected Dimension: </div>
    </p>
```

And below is the **.JS** code where this function is being implemented.

```
       var select = d3.select("#hideAxis").append("select").on("change",lostAxis);
        var options = select.selectAll('option')
        .data(d3.keys(pc0.dimensions()));

         options
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function(d) {return d;})
        .text(function(d) {return d;});

        function lostAxis() {
        pc0.hideAxis(this.value);
        }
```

This is motivated by the bundling example code which is also mentioned below :

```
    var select = d3.select("#bundleDimension").append("select").on("change", changeBundle);

    var options = select.selectAll('option')
    .data(d3.keys(pc0.dimensions()));

    options
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d) {return d;})
    .text(function(d) {return d;});

    function changeBundle() {
    pc0.bundleDimension(this.value);
    }
```